# Get a value from a Scala map with a wildcard key type

Tags: scala

I have a `Map` whose key is given as a subtype of a class.  I am unable to get values from the map using a variable typed as an instance of that class.

```
trait Foo { }

class FooImpl extends Foo {}
class Sample
{
    val m: Map[_ <: Foo, String] =  Map()
    val foo: Foo = new FooImpl

    // This line fails to compile
    m(foo)

    val m2: Map[Foo, String] =  Map()
    // This line compiles fine (but will throw at runtime)
    m2(foo)
}
```

I am using scala 2.12, and the wildcard version fails to compile:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /test/scala/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /test/scala/src/main/scala/Test.scala:10:7: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Sample.this.foo.type (with underlying type Foo)
[error]  required: _$1
[error]     m(foo)
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
```

Is it possible to get specific values from the first map (`m`) without doing something like `m.filter({(k,v) => k.equals(foo)})`?  In Java, I could do `m.get(foo)` and it seems unlikely that Scala would force me to be both more verbose and less clear than Java.

*Clarification*. I know that the call to `m2(foo)` will throw at runtime.  In the real case, the map contains `foo`.  My problem is the compilation error, not the runtime error.

Comment: What's wrong with `val m2: Map[Foo, String] =  Map()`
`m2.get(foo)`, which returns `Option`? `m2(foo)` throws an exception at runtime because `m2` is empty. In Java `Map<K, V>#get` has different signature `V get(Object key)`. This would correspond to `Map[Any, String]`.

Comment: The problem with using `m2` is that the Map comes from an external library with the type I used on `m`.  `m.get(foo)` fails to compile with a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

You need lower type bound for the Map ( >: instead of <: )

```
trait Foo
val foo = new Foo {}
val m: Map[_ >: Foo, String] = Map(foo -> "hi")
m(foo) // String = hi
m.get(new Foo {}) // Option[String] = None
```

After a comment question: let's say we have it with upper bound, and want to convert it to lower bound

```
val n: Map[_ <: Foo, String] = Map(foo -> "hi")
n(foo) // does not compile
def upper2lower(x: Map[_ <: Foo, String]): Map[_ >: Foo, String] = Map(x.toSeq:_*)
upper2lower(n)(foo) // String = hi
```

Comment: Given that I get a map with `<:` from an external source, is there a safe way to convert it the that type?

Comment: @TroyDaniels, I updated the answer by including conversion.

Comment: @VoltyDeQua Actually in this specific case we don't need `Map[_ >: Foo, String]`. `Map[Foo, String]` seems to be enough. `Map(new FooImpl {} -> "hi", new Foo {} -> "HI")` is a `Map[Foo, String]`. Conversion method is the same `def upper2lower(x: Map[_ <: Foo, String]): Map[Foo, String] = Map(x.toSeq:_*)`.